# Debug a NodeJS application inside Docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm moving my NodeJS application to docker, and the last problem that I have encountered is debugging the application.

My setup: OSx, boot2docker, docker (based on centos), WebStorm as IDE and debugger.

Here's what I have by now:
Forward 5858 from docker to boot2docker:

```
docker run -p 5858:5858 ...
```

Forward 5858 port from boot2docker to host:

```
VBoxManage controlvm boot2docker-vm natpf1 "boot2docker5858,tcp,127.0.0.1,5858,,5858"
```

This same setup works to foreword my application ports to host machine.
Port 5858 on the other hand, doesn't seem to react if accessed from outside the docker container.
Inside the docker container it works just fine.

Any idea what can be done to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have finally figured it out.
As it seems, node listens only on 127.0.0.1:5858.

To make it listen on all ports, I installed HAProxy on the docker, that forwards the requests from 0.0.0.0:5859 to 127.0.0.1:5858.

Here's the HAProxy configuration if anybody ever needs:

```
listen l1 0.0.0.0:5859
    mode tcp
    timeout client 180000
    timeout server 180000
    timeout connect 4000
    server srv1 127.0.0.1:5858
```

And than add to your Dockerfile:

```
COPY haproxy.conf haproxy.conf
RUN haproxy -D -f /haproxy.conf
```